# save a photo with a specific name and compressed size in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want to take a photo and save it with a specific name and with compressed size (low quality). How do I do it? The image is getting saved with some random name on Android device and simulator.

```
String filePath = Capture.capturePhoto();
if(filePath != null) {                
try {
     ImageIO io = ImageIO.getImageIO();
     io.saveAndKeepAspect(filePath,
        FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath()+"testImage.jpg", 
        ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 100, 100, 0.1f, true, false);

     InputStream inputStream = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().
getAppHomePath()+"testImage.jpg");

     Image readImage = Image.createImage(inputStream);
     Util.cleanup(inputStream);
     imgViewer.setImage(readImage);

     } catch(IOException err) {
       err.printStackTrace();
     }
     hi.add(imgViewer);
     hi.show();
```

Comment: When you say size do you mean size in MB?

Comment: yes, size in MB

Comment: Use kaya's answer in a loop where you shrink the size of the images width/height (there is a version of the same method that accepts dimensions) until the size in MB matches your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar, but i used the Storage, altough i added a comment with FileSystemStorage for you.
These lines create the files under the name i declare in the outputStream.

```
//OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(fileName);
OutputStream os = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(fileName);
ImageIO.getImageIO().save(img, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 0.9f);
os.close();
```

EDIT: heres an example with your code mixed with the lines i provided, it works fine on the simulator for me.

```
        String filePath = Capture.capturePhoto();
        if (filePath != null) {
            try {
                Image img = Image.createImage(filePath);
                OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "xyz.jpg");
                ImageIO.getImageIO().save(img, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 0.9f);
                os.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

[image: source example on eclipse with simulator]

Comment: It's still storing the image with a random name.